# Apache: enter one of virtual hosts via url

Tags: virtualhost, apache-2.4

By entering my public ip, browser will show page from this dir: /var/www/html.

I have 2 virtual hosts in /var/www/host1 and /var/www/host2.
By entering locally "host1.server1" or "host2.server1" in browser's adress bar, it's going to open one of these pages.

My question: how to enter those from my public ip?  "12.34.56.78~/host1.server1"?

Answer (score 1):

By browsing the ip, the first one in alphabetical order from the site-enabled folder is choosen.

Comment: And how to enter second or third?

Comment: You can only enter the first via IP. For the other vhosts you must specify the matching Host header in your request.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new additional virtual host using the ip address as the server name and pointing to the '/var/www' folder.  Then accessing your folders should be simple as 12.34.56.78/host1 and 12.34.56.78/host2  For example, in my apache2 httpd-vhosts.conf I have the following:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/
    ServerName 12.34.56.78
    ErrorLog logs/mydomain-error_log
    CustomLog logs/mydomain-access_log common
<Directory /var/www/>
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
        Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Alternatively, you may want to use name based hosting and (assuming you have a domain) point both host1.domain and host2.domain to the same ip address and add those hostnames as serveralias's in apache config.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are using name based virtual hosts (i.e. Apache looks at the host name in the request from the browser and uses that to determine which virtual host should service that particular request).

In this case, you could use a hosts file to point the relevant host names to your public IP (this essentially takes the place of DNS and is handy for testing sites when you don't want to make DNS changes or don't want to wait for DNS changes to take effect).  In Windows the hosts file is at c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts and in linux it's at /etc/hosts.  The format of the file is straightforward (just look at the samples in the files and you'll understand).

You can verify that your hosts entry is working by pinging the host name after you've added it to the hosts file and confirming that the IP address displayed by ping is the one you put in the hosts file.

Keep in mind that using a hosts file will only work for the particular computer on which you've edited the hosts file, so like I said it's useful if you need to test something, but it won't do anything at all for other computers.

Alternatively, you could add a different socket binding to each virtual host in your Apache config.  For instance, you could have all NameVirtualHosts listening on *:80, but you could also add a second port to each virtual host, such as *:81, *:82, etc.  That way you could get to those sites by going to http://:81.

Because you've said you want to access the site by your public IP, I'm assuming that the server itself has a private IP (i.e. RFC 1918 network) and you are using port forwarding on your router/firewall to forward port 80 on a public IP to port 80 on your private IP.  In this circumstance, you may not be able to browse to the public IP from another inside host and would instead have to address the server by its private IP, it depends on your router/firewall.  In that circumstance, split horizon DNS may be something you want to look into as it will return the private IP of the server for inside hosts and the public IP of the server for outside hosts.  You can learn about split horizon DNS on Google.